# What case follows 'of' in this phrase - nominative or accusative? (i.e. 'of he' or 'of him'?)

Tags: grammar

> . . . the way of being of HE who is without end

This feels wrong - surely it should be

> . . . of HIM who is without end . . . ?

Comment: There's quite some confusion about nomenclature going on here. A noun is a part of speech. A noun is *not* a case. And while the accusative case is also referred to as the objective case, an *object* itself is not a case, either. Lastly, *he* is not a noun to begin with, but a pronoun. So, what you really meant to ask is if the nominative or the accusative case should be used here.

Comment: I'm 95+% sure that I've corrected the question.

Comment: @Susan Gerard: Undirected comments are taken as being (and should normally only be) addressed to the OP / answer-giver – not the previous commenter. Though a starting ellipsis can sometimes be useful for a follow-on halfwitticism. I'll add that I'm pretty sure what the OP is asking in this post, and that I consider editing a good option. Sadly, that sometimes (as here) makes some valid comments look out of place.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those situations where we seem to require a word to have a foot in two camps.

Because he / him is a prepositional complement, the 'rule' demands we use the objective case, here **him**.

Because here the post-modifier of he / him needs the relative pronoun *who* rather than *whom*, as 'whom is without end' is obviously wrong, there is a jarring juxtaposition if we write 'him who'.

The 'nice' way round this is to use the caseless 'the man' etc:

> . . . the way of being of The One who is without end

but the 'rule that wins' when sticking with the pronoun is objective following preposition:

. . . the way of being of Him who is without end . . .

This construction is quite common in the [KJV and later versions of the Bible, and hymns](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all#hl=all&q=%22of+him+who%22).

Fowler seems to support 'everything comes to him who waits', and Wiki does but says it sounds rather archaic.

Usage does, however, seem to be [changing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comes+to+him+who+waits%2Ccomes+to+he+who+waits&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomes%20to%20him%20who%20waits%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomes%20to%20he%20who%20waits%3B%2Cc0).

This will no doubt be encouraged by Rowling's use of phrases such as "the downfall of He Who Must Not Be Named" (which can be analysed as the downfall of X where X is a six-word lexeme) (actually a nickname!)

Answer (score 1):

The OP is correct; however, most modern speakers do not use or understand this structure and so could produce the incorrect version through ignorance or even for an intentionally humorous effect.

Using structures in which a relative pronoun directly follows a personal pronoun is archaic usage and only current in quotes of older literature or folk sayings or (often humorous) imitations of such things. As a result, the grammar that used to apply to such structures is no longer natively understood by any modern speakers and is mastered by only a small educated minority.

The instances where a subject pronoun is followed by a relative pronoun in the subjective case are probably the most common and the most prominent in older literature. Modern speakers tend generally to overuse the objective case, compared with older usage, and so often hypercorrect to the subject case of pronouns whenever they are trying to speak formally and are unsure of proper usage.

In modern usage, the quoted text would be said as something like "the one who is without end"; however, even that version would not be said in everyday language even by educated speakers.

Comment: There is the accepted idiom [Everything comes to him who waits](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Everything+comes+to+him+who+waits) [half a million Google hits]. But then there are a third of a million for the 'incorrect' version. This probably means that neither should now be classed as 'unacceptable'. Many believe that grammar is sposta describe actual usage rather than dictate it.

Comment: One more really good reason not to talk about "case" in English. All signs are that case plays no systematic role in anyone's English grammar, and that it's in fact been dead in English for a long time.

Comment: @JohnLawler The scare quotes are the answer. :)